# Чтение файла блоками

Tags: golang

Задача разбить файл на части

```
MByteCount := 5
LenBuf := (1024 * 1024) * MByteCount
buf := make([]byte, LenBuf)

info, _ := os.Stat(file)
fmt.Println(info.Size())

fmt.Println("-----")

pos, err := f.Read(buf)
for err != io.EOF {
    fmt.Println(len(buf[:pos]))
    f.Seek(int64(pos), 1)
    pos, err = f.Read(buf)
}
fmt.Println(len(buf[:pos]))
```

результат

```
104365561
-----
5242880
5242880
5242880
5242880
5242880
5242880
5242880
5242880
5242880
5242880
0
```

но если 104365561 / на 5242880 должно получиться 20 частей, а тут 10, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f.Seek(int64(pos), 1)
```

Параметр 0 - означает смещение относительно начала файла.
Параметр 1 - означает смещение относительно текущего положения.
Если вы используете последовательное чтение, то вам в принципе не нужно использовать смещение.

Comment: хм, точно. Спасибо